# Trying to make a multiplexed counter with a MSP430

Tags: c, microcontroller, msp430, multiplexing, code-composer

I'm currently trying to get a counter from 30 to 0 with a 4 digit 7 segment display using a msp430f5529 launchpad but I can't make it count and the display only shows "1". I don't know where the mistake could be, since I'm pretty new at microcontrollers. I'm using code composer studio to make this code.

```
#include <msp430.h>

#define delay_ms 100

int main(void) { WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;  // stop watchdog timer 

volatile unsigned int valor=30; int unidades = valor%10; int decenas = valor/10;
P2DIR = 0xFF; // Todo el puerto 2 de salida (segmentos)
PJDIR = 0x0F; // Bits de salida PJ.3 PJ.2 PJ.1 PJ.0 (digitos)

while(1)
{
    PJOUT &=~ 0xFF;
    PJOUT |= 0x08;
    for(valor=30;valor>0;valor++)
    {
        imprimir_numero(decenas);
        __delay_cycles(delay_ms);
        PJOUT &=~ 0xFF;
        PJOUT |= 0x04;
        imprimir_numero(unidades);
        __delay_cycles(delay_ms);
    } // Termina for

    valor--;
} 

return 0;
}

void imprimir_numero (unsigned int numero)
{
    P2OUT &=~ 0xFF; // Forzar todos los bits a estar apagados
    switch(numero)
    {
    case 0: P2OUT |= 0x3F;
        break;
    case 1: P2OUT |= 0x06;
        break;
    case 2: P2OUT |= 0x5B;
        break;
    case 3: P2OUT |= 0x4F;
        break;
    case 4: P2OUT |= 0x66;
        break;
    case 5: P2OUT |= 0x6D;
        break;
    case 6: P2OUT |= 0x7D;
        break;
    case 7: P2OUT |= 0x07;
        break;
    case 8: P2OUT |= 0x7F;
        break;
    case 9: P2OUT |= 0x6F;
        break;
    }
}
```

I tried to change the __delay_cycles and using a for function as well (maybe I didn't implement it the right way). I was expecting to get a counter from 30 to 0 with a 4 digit 7 segment display by multiplexing it but didn't seem to work. The result I got was just my displays turning on and off showing "1" in a cycle.

Comment: You need `valor` to count backwards, so updating it with `valor++` in the loop is wrong to begin with. What will happen right now is your loop starts at 30, then steps to 31, 32, _etc_ all the way up until the `unsigned int` wraps to zero. At that point the loop will finally fail to meet the continuation condition of `valor > 0`. So, you must decrement instead: `valor--`. Additionally, you appear to expect that `unidades` and `decenas` act as functions just because you declared `valor` as volatile. That's not how this works. You initialized them once only, and they never change in the loop.

Comment: You were right the value variable. I didn't notice when I was writing it. Thank you!

Comment: The problem is because you drive the displays statically. That is, you output the tens and ones within 100ms intervals respectively. However the multiplexing technique requires that you refresh each digit in a way and a rate that the human eye cannot catch any flickers when updating. For example, a 20ms of update interval in total (for all digits) will be good enough to create a constant-looking displays. You would show each digit during 5ms before you switch the next one. The end result would be a stable looking display that shows the value of each corresponding digit constantly.

Comment: Another problem in your current code is that you don't convert the value to Binary Coded Decimal (BCD) values. Deceas and unidades are defined to hold the calculated BCD value but not updated everytime you change the value in the `for(valor=30;valor>0;valor++)` loop. There is no reason that the `valor` being defined as `volatile`, it can be defined without it because compiler will not ignore it in your case.